# json_normalize to pandas dataframe with nested dict/list combos

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I try to flatten the following json:

```json
{
  "header": {
    "hotel": {
      "hotelUuid": "123",
      "hotelNumber": "abc",
      "consumptionUnits": [
        {
          "uuid": "023023030",
          "number": "0000",
          "floorNumberSpecified": false,
          "floorTypeSpecified": false,
          "position": null,
          "general": true,
          "idAtCustomer": null,
          "locations": []
        },
        {
          "uuid": "3424234234",
          "number": "0002",
          "floorNumber": 1,
          "floorNumberSpecified": true,
          "floorType": 0,
          "floorTypeSpecified": true,
          "position": null,
          "general": false,
          "idAtCustomer": "qwe2eq02",
          "locations": [
            {
              "uuid": "23423523526",
              "consecutiveNumber": "0001",
              "deviceType": 2,
              "roomcategory": "B",
              "heater": [],
              "smoking": [],
              "volumeters": [
                {
                  "deadlineDaySpecified": false,
                  "deadlineMonthSpecified": false,
                  "displayUnitSpecified": false,
                  "purposeOfUsage": "K",
                  "cDate": "2011-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "cDateSpecified": true,
                  "uuid": "v546v456v456v45",
                  "articleNumber": "42",
                  "Date": "2011-06-01T00:00:00",
                  "DateSpecified": true,
                  "serialNumber": "x234x23x42",
                  "remarkKey": null,
                  "additionalDeviceDescription": null
                }
              ],
              "components": null,
              "systemTechniqueDevices": null,
              "multipleDevices": false,
              "multipleDevicesSpecified": true,
              "powerSpecified": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uuid": "2342342623",
          "number": "0001",
          "floorNumberSpecified": false,
          "floorType": 1,
          "floorTypeSpecified": true,
          "position": null,
          "general": false,
          "idAtCustomer": "qwe2ew02",
          "locations": [
            {
              "uuid": "546v54v6v54v",
              "consecutiveNumber": "0001",
              "deviceType": 2,
              "roomcategory": "B",
              "heater": [],
              "smoking": [],
              "volumeters": [
                {
                  "deadlineDaySpecified": false,
                  "deadlineMonthSpecified": false,
                  "displayUnitSpecified": false,
                  "purposeOfUsage": "K",
                  "cDate": "2011-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "cDateSpecified": true,
                  "uuid": "4v57567bv56v546",
                  "articleNumber": "42",
                  "Date": "2011-06-01T00:00:01",
                  "DateSpecified": true,
                  "serialNumber": "cx546c45c423c",
                  "remarkKey": null,
                  "additionalDeviceDescription": null
                }
              ],
              "components": null,
              "systemTechniqueDevices": null,
              "multipleDevices": false,
              "multipleDevicesSpecified": true,
              "powerSpecified": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "locations": null
    },
    "guestID": "0815",
    "company": "acme.inc",
    "environment": "bla.bla",
    "language": null
  }
}
```

My goal is to receive a dataframe which would look like this (for a better overview I have transposed the table)

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvV3K.png)

```
hotel.hotelUuid                                                                     |   123         |   123                 |   123
hotel.hotelNumber                                                                   |   abc         |   abc                 |   abc
hotel.consumptionUnits.uuid                                                         |   023023030   |   3424234234          |   2342342623
hotel.consumptionUnits.number                                                       |   0000        |   0002                |   0001
hotel.consumptionUnits.floorNumber                                                  |   NaN         |   1                   |   NaN
hotel.consumptionUnits.floorNumberSpecified                                         |   False       |   True                |   False
hotel.consumptionUnits.floorType                                                    |   NaN         |   0                   |   1
hotel.consumptionUnits.floorTypeSpecified                                           |   False       |   True                |   True
hotel.consumptionUnits.position                                                     |   None        |   None                |   None
hotel.consumptionUnits.general                                                      |   True        |   False               |   False
hotel.consumptionUnits.idAtCustomer                                                 |   None        |   qwe2eq02            |   qwe2ew02
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.uuid                                      |   NaN         |   23423523526         |   546v54v6v54v
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.consecutiveNumber                         |   NaN         |   0001                |   0001
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.deviceType                                |   NaN         |   2                   |   2
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.roomcategory                              |   NaN         |   B                   |   B
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.heater                                    |   NaN         |   NAN                 |   NAN
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.smoking                                   |   NaN         |   NaN                 |   NAN
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.deadlineDaySpecified           |   NaN         |   False               |   False
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.deadlineMonthSpecified         |   NaN         |   False               |   False
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.displayUnitSpecified           |   NaN         |   False               |   False
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.purposeOfUsage                 |   NaN         |   K                   |   K
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.cDate                          |   NaN         |   2011-01-01T00:00:00 |   2011-01-01T00:00:00
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.cDateSpecified                 |   NaN         |   True                |   True
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.uuid                           |   NaN         |   v546v456v456v45     |   4v57567bv56v546
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.articleNumber                  |   NaN         |   42                  |   42
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.Date                           |   NaN         |   2011-06-01T00:00:00 |   2011-06-01T00:00:01
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.DateSpecified                  |   NaN         |   True                |   True
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.serialNumber                   |   NaN         |   x234x23x42          |   cx546c45c423c
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.remarkKey                      |   NaN         |   None                |   None
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.volumeters.additionalDeviceDescription    |   NaN         |   None                |   None
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.components                                |   NaN         |   None                |   None
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.systemTechniqueDevices                    |   NaN         |   None                |   None
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.multipleDevices                           |   NaN         |   False               |   False
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.multipleDevicesSpecified                  |   NaN         |   True                |   True
hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations.powerSpecified                            |   NaN         |   False               |   False
hotel.locations                                                                     |   None        |   None                |   None
guestID                                                                             |   0815        |   0815                |   0815
company                                                                             |   acme.inc    |   acme.inc            |   acme.inc
environment                                                                         |   bla.bla     |   bla.bla             |   bla.bla
language                                                                            |   None        |   None                |   None
```

First I tried:

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(json_object)
```

Which lead to only one line, with

```
hotelUuid | hotelNumber | consumptionUnits            | locations
123       | abc         | [{'uuid': '023023030', ...    None
```

So I tried:

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(json_object["header"]["hotel"], 
                       record_path=["consumptionUnits"], 
                       meta=['guestID', 'company', 'environment', 'language', 'hotelUuid', 'hotelNumber', 'locations'] ,
                       errors='ignore',
                       max_level=10,
                       meta_prefix='meta-',
                       record_prefix='.')
```

With this approach I have two problems.
1.) I lose the information 'guestID', 'company', 'environment', 'language' while 'hotelUuid', 'hotelNumber', 'locations' meta is fine.
2.) The .locations (hotel.consumptionUnitslocations.locations not the hotel.locations) was again summarized in one column.

I also tried

```py
...
df = pd.json_normalize(json_object,
record_path=["header", "hotel", "consumptionUnits"],
errors='ignore',
...
```

but then I received the error

> KeyError: 'guestID'
> even with error='ignore'

How could I solve this two problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def json_to_list(unflat: dict) -> list:
    '''
    Flatten dict
    '''
    json_list = []
    def parse(val, path):
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for x in val:
                parse(val[x], f"{path}.{x}")
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            for i, x in enumerate(val):
                if i==0:
                    parse(x, f"{path}")
                else:
                    parse(x, f"{path}[{i}]")
        else:
            json_list.append([path[1:], val])
    parse(unflat, '')
    return json_list

pd.DataFrame(json_to_list(json_object))
```

Output

```
0                                                              header.hotel.hotelUuid                     123  
1                                                            header.hotel.hotelNumber                     abc  
2                                                  header.hotel.consumptionUnits.uuid               023023030  
3                                                header.hotel.consumptionUnits.number                    0000  
4                                  header.hotel.consumptionUnits.floorNumberSpecified                   False  
5                                    header.hotel.consumptionUnits.floorTypeSpecified                   False  
6                                              header.hotel.consumptionUnits.position                    None  
7                                               header.hotel.consumptionUnits.general                    True  
8                                          header.hotel.consumptionUnits.idAtCustomer                    None  
9                                               header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].uuid              3424234234  
10                                            header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].number                    0002  
11                                       header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].floorNumber                       1  
12                              header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].floorNumberSpecified                    True  
13                                         header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].floorType                       0  
14                                header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].floorTypeSpecified                    True  
15                                          header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].position                    None  
16                                           header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].general                   False  
17                                      header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].idAtCustomer                qwe2eq02  
18                                    header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].locations.uuid             23423523526  
19                       header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].locations.consecutiveNumber                    0001  
20                              header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].locations.deviceType                       2  
21                            header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].locations.roomcategory                       B  
22         header.hotel.consumptionUnits[1].locations.volumeters.deadlineDaySpecified                   False  
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I receivea df.shape of 75X2 instead of 4X40.